# Proguard: How to keep inner @interfaces?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

Error is:

```
com.github.florent37.expectanim.core.Expectations: can't find referenced class com.github.florent37.expectanim.core.Expectations$GravityIntDef
```

Source code:

```
public class Expectations {
...
  @IntDef(value = {Gravity.LEFT, Gravity.RIGHT, Gravity.END, Gravity.START, Gravity.TOP, Gravity.BOTTOM})
    @interface GravityIntDef {
    }
...
```

I tried to make this:

```
-keep class com.github.florent37.expectanim.core.** { *; }
-keep enum com.github.florent37.expectanim.core.** { *; }
-keep interface com.github.florent37.expectanim.core.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class com.github.florent37.expectanim.core.** {
    *;
}
-keepclassmembers enum com.github.florent37.expectanim.core.** {
    *;
}
-keepclassmembers interface com.github.florent37.expectanim.core.** {
    *;
}

-keep public @interface com.github.florent37.expectanim.core.Expectations.GravityIntDef
-keep public @interface com.github.florent37.expectanim.core.Expectations.GravityScaleVerticalIntDef
-keep public @interface com.github.florent37.expectanim.core.Expectations.GravityScaleHorizontalIntDef
```

Comment: @Thomas it's this custom library https://github.com/florent37/ExpectAnim

Comment: @Thomas oh thanks, i forgot about `dontwarn com.github.florent37.expectanim.**`

Comment: Drop the `public` from those last `-keep` lines? The `@interface` isn't public.